# How to save a local PDF file to iBooks or an other PDF reader by clicking a button?

Tags: ios, pdf, button, save

I have an Xcode iOS app. I want to load a local stored PDF file by clicking a button to iBooks or another PDF readable button.
How can I save a local PDF file to iBooks (or an other PDF reader) by clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

Use "openUrl" in the action of that button for iBooks which opens the given file in openURL in iBooks which automatically adds it to iBooks or give save option to it.

Check with canOpenURL before using to check whether iBooks installed or not.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:@"itms-books://your-pdf-path"];

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm new in programming and Xcode. Unfortunately, I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: openURL is used for opening other apps with custom URL scheme. "itms-books://" is custom url to open iBooks. Just add your Local PDF path in place of "your-pdf-path".

Comment: @David:StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to try to write this and come back with a specific problem. Please see the FAQ on how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask